# Javscriptencode Url Path for use in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, xss

I try to pass the parameter _trackPageview to Google Analytics.

I now use

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', <%=AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path ) %> ])
```

The resulting Hml for "/Home/Index" is:

```
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '\x2fHome\x2fIndex' ]);
```

How should I handle the forward slash? Will "\x2" be displayed ok in Google Analytics? Or Is it save to replace \x2 with forward slash?

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', <%=AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path).Replace("\x2","/") %> ])
```

**EDIT:**

I cant use `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);` without the path parameter because the original path contains the language which I dont want to track ( /de/home/index needs to get tracked as /home/index )

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the 2nd argument for `_trackPageview`. By default it will record the current url (including query params). That url, on any given page is assembled/taken from `document.location`.

### Other solutions:

- The `replace` solution you already mentioned is actually good enough.
- Leave the \x2f in the path, it isn't hurting anything other than your eyes/brain.
- Could you do this in pure javascript by using `document.location` or `document.location.pathname`? I'd guess the query or hash part of the URL is the only thing you'd need worry about for an XSS attack.
- Escape the path instead of encoding it by wrapping it in a string and escaping quotes. You could also just strip any quote marks.
- Don't encode the path, it most likely is fine (unless it is un-sanitized and from you user data); rather just encode the query and hash.

Comment: Not passing the parameter path is a nice solution. But I have to fiddle with it (see my edit.)

Comment: Yea I don't think fiddling is possible. However, it is just using javascript's build document.location functions. You should open chrome's console and mess with it a bit. 

Alternatively using the server side code isn't bad. It does however force you to leave google analytics on your html pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to go with a JavaScript solution.  Try slicing the array to remove the language prefix and join to combine the path:

```
pathnameArray = document.location.pathname.split('/').slice(2);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], '/' + pathnameArray.join('/'));
```